# Node.JS on Google Cloud Run with cloud SQLError: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<instancename...>

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I'm not able to connect the cloudrun service to cloudsql.

I am using Sequelize and here is my connection section!

```
  let sequelize = new (<any> Sequelize) (
  DATABASE_DATABASE,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
      dialect: 'postgres'
      dialectOptions: {
        socketPath: `/cloudsql/${DATABASE_HOST}`,
        supportBigNumbers: true,
        bigNumberStrings: true
      },
      host: `/cloudsql/${DATABASE_HOST}`,
      port: DATABASE_PORT,
      logging: false,
    },
  );
```

PS: Apparently everything is configured correctly, that is,
The cloudsql service is connected to the specific cloudrun service,
they are in the same region, the AMIs are released ...

My unsuccessful attempts were:

1. The code snippet above returns: Error: connect ENOENT / cloudsql / <instancename ...>,
2. If I change the host to 127.0.0.1 = connection refused 127.0.0.1:5432,
3. Putting the native property in the connection: true = Error: Connection not found
4. direct connection attempt by PG = Error: connect ENOENT / cloudsql / <instancename ...>
5. I created another project, other permissions and the error continues
6. I changed the zone and the error continues

Another attempt was:
I tried to create VPC without a server for private IP connection enabled in cloudsql, but I get timeout in cloudrun

What I had left was to enable the cloudsql public network to access 0.0.0.0/0 and the application is working fine.

I'm out of ideas and need help connecting using /cloudsql/

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview you need to connect to the database server using the hostname/ip address, not a socket. configure the database to allow access from the IP where your app is running. Connect using the username and password for the database.

Comment: Edit your question and include the Cloud Run deploy command.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run connects to Cloud SQL over Unix sockets.

You'll want to use the instance connection name in the socket path instead of the host IP address. This will follow the format `project-name:region-name:instance-name`. You might also need to append the suffix `s.PGSQL.5432`. The full socket path should look like `"/cloudsql/project-name:region-name:instance-name.s.PGSQL.5432"` If you're using the socket path, you can remove the `host` and `port` connection arguments